# Can I force system-wide software rendering on Windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, graphics-card, bsod, flash-player

I have a laptop (hp elitebook 6930p) that has some kind of unspecified (probably overheating/faulty memory) problem that i think related to the graphics card that causes BSODs/crashes (often without leaving a memory dump behind).

The graphic card model (as reported in device manager) is

> Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family

I think it may be integrated in cpu :(

As the guarantee expired a long time ago i was looking into a way to actually use it for web surfing\youtube without crashes.

The installed OS are Windows 10 (Technical Preview) and Windows XP in a Dual boot configuration.

Windows XP has not yet crashed (probably because the UI does not use the graphics card acceleration, and because I did never run any program that uses the graphics card acceleration), while Windows 10 crashes unexpectedly.

I want to ditch Windows XP (because of internet exposition), but in order to do so I have to make Windows 10 stable/usable.

So I would like to force software rendering on Windows 7+ operating systems.

But, even if I could force that setting for the explorer UI, I am unsure of what would happen with other applications like Chrome/Firefox (I read they are accelerated) and plugins like flash player(about it i really have no idea). For example (on win10) VLC takes a lot more time to crash the system than using the default video player.

I think I have to force it system-wide because of the above concerns.

*Right now I am using the Porteus linux distribution booting from SD card and even youtube works. It is a good compromise between security and functionality. But I am mostly a windows guy.*

Comment: Disassemble the laptop and replace the thermal pad on the Gpu, give the heatsinks and fan a good cleaning while you are in there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Device Manager and remove the Display Adapter manually.  Then add the Generic SVGA graphics card and you should be good to go.  I dont have XP handy to give you step-by-step directions, but it should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: I will try this solution on Windows 10. I don't need instructions for XP as my objective is uninstalling it and keeping only Windows 10 (without crashes).

Comment: Update: I did try doing so but the screen turned off and wouldn't turn on. So I went my way blindly using START+R to use the shutdown command.

Upon reboot the display flickered as windows automatically reinstalled the correct driver.

I think there is some option for this.